# Flutter - how can i use use stream controller without reloading the stream itself

Tags: flutter, stream, reload

```
 StreamController<UserModel> _controller = StreamController<UserModel>.broadcast();

getFriendsName() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString("token");
  var username = prefs.getString("username");
  final response = await http
      .post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.111:3000/friendNames"),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "$token"
          },
          body: jsonEncode({"username": username}))
      .then((value) => value)
      .catchError((e) => print(e));
  UserModel usermodel = UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  return _controller.sink.add(usermodel);
 //return usermodel;

}
```

i created an infinite loop that reload data every 0 second

void initState() {

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 0), (_) => getFriendsName());

super.initState();
```

}

here is the stream builder

```
StreamBuilder<UserModel>( /
              stream: _controller.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (snapshot.data!.msg == "no friends to chat with") {
                    return Center(child: Text("No friends found."));
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.msg.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data!.msg[index]),
                           subtitle:
                                Text("${snapshot.data!.msg1![index]}"),
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                "http://192.168.0.111:3000/getImage/${snapshot.data!.msg[index]}?v=${Random().nextInt(100)}",
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () async {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return (ChatRoom(
                                    snapshot.data!.msg[index]));
                              }));
                          
                            },
                          );
                        });
                  }
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

What im asking for is a way to use streambuilder and listen to changes  without the need of looping the stream infinitly.
so any propositions

Comment: instead of `Timer.periodic` use `Stream.periodic` or `Stream.fromIterable`

Comment: the problem is that it produces Bad state: Stream has already been listened to error

Comment: this is because you call `Stream.listen` method somewhere

Comment: no that's because im using streambuilder in a tab bar which i couldnt find a solution yet

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that - this error simply means that `StreamBuilder` tried to `listen` the stream that is already listened to

Comment: i mean when i go from tab to tab where is the streambuilder it's like i relisten to the stream

Comment: btw tnx for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by changing Timer to Stream and adding as .asBroadcastStream()
and it should look like this

```
return Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 0))
    .asyncMap((event) => getFriendsName0()).asBroadcastStream();
```